# Modify PHP generated HTML with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been using some calendar widgets over time in my own project but I recently thought that they do not match up with my expectations. So I recently decided to build my own "calendar widget".

I've got those two files (simplified for demonstration):

**index.php**

```
<div id="displayCalendar"></div>
<div id="displayStaff"></div>

<script>
  function selectDay(selected) {
    if(selected != $('#date').val()){
      var day = "#" + selected;
      $('.calendar-day-active').removeClass("calendar-day-active");
      $(day).addClass("calendar-day-active");

      $('#date').val(selected);

      getInfo();
    }
  }

  function displayCalendar(attrib = ""){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'loadCalendar.php',
      data: { attrib: attrib },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#calendar_display').html(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**loadCalendar.php**

```
<?php
  // this will be displayed for each day in the selected month
  echo '<div class="col border border-success calendar-day" id="calendar '.$day.$month.$year.'" onClick="selectDay(`'.$day.$month.$year.'`);">';
?>
```

The Problem now is, that when I am clicking on a day of the calendar, the class **calendar-day-active** is removed from the old element, but the clicked one will not get this class added.

I have also tried to select and change the element through Chromes Dev Tools, without success.

Is there a way to modify html which was generated using php and ajax?
(Because the php file was loaded through ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have spaces in your id fields, you should use a different type of selector:

```
function selectDay(selected) {
 if(selected != $('#date').val()){
   var day = selected;
   $('.calendar-day-active').removeClass("calendar-day-active");
   $("div[id='calendar " + day + "']").addClass("calendar-day-active");

   $('#date').val(selected);

   getInfo();
 }
}
```

Or, you could just replace that space with an underscore and you're good.

Comment: I did not think that the solution would be that simple :D
Thank you very much for your help, it worked perfectly!